# Anygantt Project Plan Change Scale

Tags: anychart

Is it possible yet to set the scale of timeline in a ganttProject graph in Anychart - for example, to be only quarters? I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize timeline header using the header() method:
https://api.anychart.com/7.12.0/anychart.core.gantt.TimelineHeader

```
var timeline = chart.getTimeline();
var currentHeader = timeline.header();
```

Timeline header supports levels customization, like:

```
currentHeader.lowLevel(false);
currentHeader.midLevel(true);
currentHeader.topLevel(true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anycharts/ou032nye/